# Hibernate columnDefinition to mediumblob not working

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

When I set

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "MEDIUMBLOB")
private byte[] data;
```

And generate database, I always get in database **TINYBLOB**. I dont understand why, can you help me?

Where is a problem?

I try a lot of annotations but it doesn't work.
I am new in hibernate.

Or.. there is a another (maybe easy way) how to save file(xml) to database?

Answer (score 1):

```
    @Column(length = 16777215)
```

is the alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Change the Definition of JPA to following

```
import java.sql.Blob;
import javax.persistence.Lob;

@Column
@Lob
private Blob data;
```

If the data is of type, byte[], then covert using [SerialBlob](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/sql/rowset/serial/SerialBlob.html).

```
Blob blobData = new SerialBlob(byteArrayData);
```

This helps in storing the data in medium Blob format. If the tables are generated using JPA this can be used to generate medium blob.